# Pattern matching with OR and WHEN clauses

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I have problem with pattern matching not compiling when it's expected

Current simplified version looks like this

```ml
match smth with
| pattern1 when isSomething pattern1 ->
   doWork()
| pattern2 when isSomething pattern2 ->
   doWork()
| _ -> () // do nothing
```

Problem here is that there is duplication of body in different cases

I've tried to use [OR pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching#or-pattern) to transform it to this

```ml
match smth with
| pattern1 when isSomething pattern1
| pattern2 when isSomething pattern2 ->
   doWork()
| _ -> () // do nothing
```

But it gives `Unexpected symbol '|' in pattern matching. Expected '->' or other token. F# Compiler 10`

Attempts to surround `isSomething` with parens doesn't help. How to avoid duplication in that case?

Original code

```ml
match state.SearchOptions with
| { Pattern = empty } when String.IsNullOrEmpty empty ->
    ValueSome (i, p, state.SelectedConfiguration, state.Solution.Configurations)
| { Pattern = pattern; IsRegex = true; IsCaseSensitive = true } when Regex.isMatch p.Name pattern ->
    ValueSome (i, p, state.SelectedConfiguration, state.Solution.Configurations)
| { Pattern = pattern; IsRegex = true; IsCaseSensitive = false } when Regex.isMatchCaseInsensitive p.Name pattern ->
    ValueSome (i, p, state.SelectedConfiguration, state.Solution.Configurations)
| { Pattern = pattern; IsRegex = false; IsCaseSensitive = true } when p.Name.Contains(pattern, StringComparison.InvariantCulture) ->
    ValueSome (i, p, state.SelectedConfiguration, state.Solution.Configurations)
| { Pattern = pattern; IsRegex = false; IsCaseSensitive = false } when p.Name.Contains(pattern, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ->
    ValueSome (i, p, state.SelectedConfiguration, state.Solution.Configurations)
| _ -> ValueNone
```

Comment: This is impossible in F#. The `when` guard applies to all the pipe-separated patterns together, you can't have a separate `when` guard for each one. To avoid the duplication, give a name to the resulting value.

Comment: Have you considered remodelling SearchOptions? A discriminated union ` EmptyPattern | RegExPattern of (string*bool) | PlainPattern of (string*bool) ` might help here.

Comment: @Guran, in the end I've decided to use `if` that looks decent enough [source](https://github.com/jl0pd/LightSolutionConfigurationManager/blob/a498d4beaeb3f9b993f19ad073edf22170d13c02/src/LightSolutionManager/MainView.fs#L318)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, this cannot be done - the `when` clause applies to the whole clause. I think there are three alternative approaches.

First of all, you could define the result value as a variable before the `match` expression and then just return this from all four cases (as suggested in the comment).

Second, you could actually write this as a plain `if` expression:

```
let so = state.SearchOptions
if String.IsNullOrEmpty so.Pattern then 
  ValueSome (i, p, state.SelectedConfiguration, state.Solution.Configurations)
elif ( so.IsRegex && so.IsCaseSensitive && 
       Regex.isMatch p.Name so.Pattern )
  || ( so.IsRegex && not so.IsCaseSensitive && 
       Regex.isMatchCaseInsensitive p.Name so.Pattern )
  || ( not so.IsRegex && so.IsCaseSensitive && 
       p.Name.Contains(so.Pattern, StringComparison.InvariantCulture) )
  || ( not so.IsRegex && not so.IsCaseSensitive && 
       p.Name.Contains(so.Pattern, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ) then
    ValueSome (i, p, state.SelectedConfiguration, state.Solution.Configurations)
else ValueNone
```

Another option would be to use active patterns - that way, you can integrate the conditions into the pattern itself. Something like this should do the trick:

```
let (|RegexMatch|_|) input pattern = 
  if Regex.isMatch input pattern then Some() else None
let (|RegexMatchInsensitive|_|) input pattern = 
  if Regex.isMatchCaseInsensitive input pattern then Some() else None
let (|Contains|_|) (input:string) pattern
  input.Contains(pattern, StringComparison.InvariantCulture)
let (|ContainsInsensitive|_|) (input:string) pattern
  input.Contains(pattern, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)

match state.SearchOptions with
| { Pattern = empty } when String.IsNullOrEmpty empty ->
    ValueSome (i, p, state.SelectedConfiguration, state.Solution.Configurations)
| { Pattern = Match p.Name; IsRegex = true; IsCaseSensitive = true } 
| { Pattern = RegexMatchInsensitive p.Name; IsRegex = true; IsCaseSensitive = false } 
| { Pattern = Contains p.Name; IsRegex = false; IsCaseSensitive = true } 
| { Pattern = ContainsInsensitive p.Name; IsRegex = false; IsCaseSensitive = false } ->
    ValueSome (i, p, state.SelectedConfiguration, state.Solution.Configurations)
| _ -> ValueNone
```

If I was doing this in just one place, I would probably go with either option one or two (depending on what you find more readable). If you are doing more things like this, the third option is a nice alternative.

Comment: Would the 3rd option be slower when it falls to the last option? Would it try all the pattern matches and fail or is it smart enough to try the fast conditions first?

Comment: @AMieres I think it could be - though I think this depends on the order of things. I guess that if it first started with the quicker `bool` patterns, it would not actually have to run the match. It is worth checking, but I guess the difference is not really that significant.